# How to access Rails model parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, belongs-to

I have a model, say `Child`, that `belongs_to` some other model `Parent`. For some instance `child` can I type `child.parent` in rails console to get the parent without explicitly adding `child_id` as a column in the Parents model?

Comment: Have you tried it? Also, see the [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-belongs-to-association).

Answer (score 1):

From what you've described you've got the following code:

```
class Child
  belongs_to Parent
end

class Parent
end
```

You can call `child.parent` since the parent foreign_key is defined on `child` and not on `parent`. You'll need a database migration to add the `belongs_to` relationship if you haven't done that already.